# How can I get `+vterm/toggle` to popup from the right side of the screen instead of from the bottom?

Tags: doom

I am using Doom Emacs, and I frequently use the vterm popup/toggle functionality (defined as `+vterm/toggle` [here](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/blob/develop/modules/term/vterm/autoload.el#L4), which is used, as the name suggests, to toggle a vterm buffer.

The default behavior is to toggle from the bottom of the screen, but I'd like it to toggle from the right side of my screen if possible.

Answer (score 6):

Credit to @henrik:

You need to use a popup rule. The default is defined [here](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/blob/develop/modules/term/vterm/config.el#L10):

> `(set-popup-rule! "^vterm" :size 0.25 :vslot -4 :select t :quit nil :ttl 0)`

Just add `side: right` and have the regex match the buffer you want, in this case `*doom:vterm-popup:main` and put this in your `config.el` inside an `after! vterm` block.

So, the final result for my case was:

```
; config.el
(after! vterm
  (set-popup-rule! "*doom:vterm-popup:main" :size 0.25 :vslot -4 :select t :quit nil :ttl 0 :side 'right)
  )
```

For more info on popup-rules, see [the doom docs.](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/blob/207ce02a3371e0bcd67c90d1d7b00aa72c8eccf2/modules/ui/popup/README.org)

Answer (score 0):

Just few notes to @jacob-pavlock answer.

If you receiving error, Invalid side 'right specified, you need to remove the `'` character.

```
; config.el
(after! vterm
  (set-popup-rule! "*doom:vterm-popup:main" :size 0.25 :vslot -4 :select t :quit nil :ttl 0 :side right)
  )
```

Comment: Where is the **'char** that you suggest to remove? I don't see a difference between the code you show and that shown in @Jacob's answer.

Comment: :side 'right -> :side right

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer only adds that behavior to projects named main (or when no project is selected).

Use `:*` to have that for all projects

```
   ; config.el
(after! vterm
  (set-popup-rule! "*doom:vterm-popup:*" :size 0.25 :vslot -4 :select t :quit nil :ttl 0 :side 'right)
  )
```